# macOS Keyboard Shortcut symbolized by underlined down arrow

Tags: macos, keyboard, final-cut-pro

I'm in Final Cut Pro (FCP) [10.6.1] and I found some useful menu options to jump to the beginning and end of the timeline. macOS shows the keyboard shortcut for menu items, and FCP is full of snazzy shortcuts, but I can't figure out what this one is. I'm on a MacBook Pro (2021 16" M1 Pro) so I don't have a full keyboard, implying that perhaps I don't have whatever keys this may need. I've tried every modifying key + the down arrow I can think of:

- Option + ↓
- Control + ↓ (does some desktop-exposé thing)
- Cmd + ↓
- Shift + ↓
- fn + ↓

...none of them seem to work. I don't have the page down key, but I've tried the keyboard shortcut for Page Down (fn + ↓). I'd prefer to not remap the shortcut if I am able to figure out what it is, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what key or key-combo the icon with the underlined down arrow symbolizes.

[image: Final Cut Pro Go To End Menu Item]

Comment: FYI, for now I've mapped them to `Beginning` == `Shift+Cmd+←` && `End` == `Shift+Cmd+→`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This portion of a chart may help

[image]

Comment: Nice! I'll try this out when I'm back on my editing machine and update your answer if it turns out fruitful.

Comment: Confirmed! That is the shortcut! fn + → == "Underlined down arrow" == "End".  Cheers!